# Warning: Illegal string offset 'key'

Tags: wordpress, string, key

I have some problems with my WordPress theme, it"s saying:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'key' in
>   `X:\Programme\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\themes\mx\inc\penguin\modules\penguin-megamenu.php`
>   on line 77

Here is the code:

```
foreach($post_fields as $field){
    $menu_item->$field['key'] = get_post_meta( $menu_item->ID, '_'.$field['name'], true );
}
return $menu_item;
```

Line:

```
$menu_item->$field['key'] = get_post_meta( $menu_item->ID,
```

is the problem like it says.

I really don't know what's going on.

Best regards.

Comment: Can you post this whole function?

Comment: Have you tried with $menu_item->{$field['key']}?